# GoogleMaps API (PHP/curl) returns ZERO_RESULT

Tags: php, json, google-maps, curl

I run into strange problem with GoogleMaps API.

Calling the following url in browser, everything works fine.
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:DE|postal_code:81823&key=[mykey]

But using same url in PHP with curl I get a ZERO_RESULT?

Calling https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:DE|postal_code:90471 it works fine in PHP and Browser.

My code in PHP:

```
$timeout    = 5;
$ch         = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
$decode     = json_decode( curl_exec( $ch ) );

curl_close( $ch );
print_r($decode);
```

returns with the first url

```
stdClass Object
(
[results] => Array
    (
    )

[status] => ZERO_RESULTS
)
```

Comment: I've called the link using my key and it's returned ZERO_RESULTS in the browser too, maybe the postal code is wrong

Comment: That is strange. I tried different browsers and get a result (even without any key): https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:DE|postal_code:81823

Comment: I changed the url to https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=81823,DE&key=[mykey] and everything works fine no even in PHP! Don't know why my first "cleaner" solution doesn't work as suspected in PHP, but this is definitely a acceptable workaround ;-)